# arr is used before its value is set

Tags: c++

Hello I have a generate array method:

```
void generateArray(double *data, int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        data[i] = rand() / ((rand() + rand()) / 2.0 + 1);
}
```

and I have below main

```
int main(void) {

    double *arr;
    generateArray(arr,40000);

    cout << arr[0];


    return 0;
}
```

it says arr is used before its value is set why? Why does not genearate array fills it? How can i fix this problem?

Comment: How is this a CUDA question?

Answer (score 3):

```
double *arr;
```

This only gives you a pointer. You haven't allocated any `double`s for it to point at and you haven't initialised the pointer to actually point anywhere. Here, you'll find it easier to declare an array of the appropriate size instead:

```
double arr[40000];
```

Passing `arr` as you are currently doing will perform array-to-pointer conversion and it will work as expected.

However, an array of 40000 `double`s is a pretty large object to have on the stack. You may prefer to dynamically allocate your array with `double* arr = new double[40000];`, but you would need to make sure you do `delete[] arr;` when you are done with it to avoid memory leaks. Instead, you might prefer to use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<double> arr(40000);
```

And simply change the first argument of `generateArray` to a `std::vector<double>&`.

Comment: You can also initialize the vector with the appropriate size, and pass a pointer to its data: `const std::size_t size = 40000; std::vector<double> arr(size); generateArray(arr.data(), size);`. Or you could make `generateArray` a template accepting any kind of OutputIterator, and pass it a pointer or a `back_insert_iterator`. Or you could use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n). Or... So many alternatives :)!

Comment: @LucTouraille Whoops, I just forget to give the size. But yes, they are all great (and better) alternatives!

Answer (score 1):

You simply give it a pointer, but never allocate any memory for the array. You want a `data = new double[count]` in your generateArray, or to simply allocate it beforehand with `double arr[40000]` (or better yet, use a `vector`).

This would be preferable as:

```
std::vector<double> generateArray(int count) {
    std::vector<double> data(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        data[i] = rand() / ((rand() + rand()) / 2.0 + 1);
    }
    return data;
}
```

If you need to get array data back somehow, `vector` is guaranteed to utilize a contiguous array internally, accessible with `&v[0]` to `&v[v.size()-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the array with a size. You need to do

```
arr = new double[count];
```

inside the function. Like below. Don't forget to do `delete[] arr;` when you're done!

```
void generateArray(double *data, int count) {
    arr = new double[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        data[i] = rand() / ((rand() + rand()) / 2.0 + 1);
}
```

Another option would be doing `double *arr = new double[40000]` outside the function.